# When i create an event programmatically i can't tell Facebook that it must use timezones when user visualize it

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating an event with the Facebook PHP SDK like this

```
    $fb_event['name'] = $_POST['post_title'];
    $fb_event['description'] = $_POST['content'];
    $fb_event['start_time'] = date( "c", Ai1ec_Facebook_Event::get_facebook_start_time($event->start));
    $fb_event['location'] = "Dove ti pare basta che si aggiorni al mio timezone";
    $fb_event['street'] = "Via andrea del sarto 9";
    $fb_event['city'] = "Milan";
    $facebook = $this->facebook_instance_factory();
    try {
        $result = $facebook->api( "/me/events", "POST", $fb_event );
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        fb($e);
    }
```

the `Ai1ec_Facebook_Event::get_facebook_start_time` simply takes a timestamp and transforms it to UTC pretending that it's PST. This means that if i edecide that the EVENT starts at 8PM UTC that function returns me 3AM of the following day.

Evrything works correctly and my event is created and the problem is that if i look at the event with my user which is in TIMEZONE UTC + 2 i still se 8PM and not 10PM

This is the created event https://www.facebook.com/events/245655182207213/

It seems like Facebook it's ignoring timezones when creating this event, why?What do i have to tell facebook so that it uses standard timezones?

EDIT - After reading this article developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#timezone-less-events i realized that there is timezone field, but i can't get that to work, because if i send

```
$fb_event['timezone'] = "Europe/Sofia";
```

Facebook simply ignores that and when i query the events i get back NULL fo rthe timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has implemented "timezoneless events." What I have found this to mean is that events are always displayed to a user as though they are in that user's local time (So when I visit your event page on Facebook, I also see your event as taking place at 20:00-22:00, even though I am located at UTC-4).

The [Events API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) say that start_time and end_time should be passed a "string containing an ISO-8601 formatted date/time or a UNIX timestamp".

I recommend passing it the ISO-8601 formatted date, because if you pass it a timestamp, you need to correct that timestamp for daylight savings time (both yours and Facebook's). So for your event, your code should just look like `$fb_event['start_time'] = date( "c", $event->start);`

Comment: Yes but i would like to obtain is that if you are in UTC + 4 and the event i'm creating is UTC 20.00, you see 24.00 and me that i'm in UTC +2 i see 22

Comment: And if i pass date( "c", $event->start) which would give me 22.00 as time and +2 as timezone i would still get an event that start at 20.00

Comment: Llook here, they are talking about a timezone field in events but i can't find it https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#timezone-less-events and i can't set it.

Comment: There is a checkbox in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/advanced you can toggle to get it back temporarily. But why bother? It will be fully deprecated on July 5. If you created your app recently, you may not get this option.

Comment: Not true. If you create an event you'll see it as local time regardless of your location. There does appear to be something in the works where they are showing a timezone within Facebook based on the timezone of the event's venue, but it is not exposed via the API yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't do that.
I'm not sure, but:

From the documentation of the deprecated [REST API events.create](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.create/):

> Note: The start_time and end_time are the times that were inputted by
>   the event creator. **Facebook Events have no concept of timezone,** but if
>   a timezone is specified, the time will be converted to Pacific
>   (Daylight or Standard) time before being stored and displayed. But
>   when an event is displayed, no timezone is specified or implied.

And in the Event object documentation they say:

> string containing an ISO-8601 formatted date/time or a UNIX timestamp;
>   if it contains a time zone (not recommended), it will be converted to
>   Pacific time before being stored and displayed

And you might want to read this: [Correctly Parsing Graph API Event Times](http://www.senab.co.uk/2011/06/24/facebook-event-times/).

This probably does not solve your problem, but I'm afraid that there's not much on this subject.